# Cygwin + node.js + socket.io a no go

Tags: node.js, cygwin, socket.io

I'm trying to get node.js all up and running on windows server 2003 x64 w/ cygwin but keep hitting walls.

It wants me to run npm as sudo but that's not an option with cygwin (command not found..)??

```
$ npm install socket.io --loglevel verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'node',
npm verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   'socket.io',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
npm verb cli   'verbose' ]
npm info using npm@1.0.1rc9
npm info using node@v0.5.0-pre
npm verb config file /home/rfitzger/.npmrc
npm verb config file /usr/local/etc/npmrc
npm verb caching /cygdrive/d/workspace/gits/hummingbird/package.json
npm verb loadDefaults hummingbird@0.0.1
npm verb from cache /cygdrive/d/workspace/gits/hummingbird/package.json
npm verb into /cygdrive/d/workspace/gits/hummingbird [ 'socket.io' ]
npm verb cache add [ 'socket.io@0.6.16', null ]
npm info addNamed [ 'socket.io', '0.6.16' ]
npm verb addNamed [ '0.6.16', '0.6.16' ]
npm verb GET socket.io/0.6.16
npm verb raw, before any munging socket.io/0.6.16
npm verb url resolving [ 'http://registry.npmjs.org/',
npm verb url resolving   './socket.io/0.6.16' ]
npm verb url resolved http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/0.6.16
npm verb url parsed { href: 'http://registry.npmjs.org/socket.io/0.6.16',
npm verb url parsed   protocol: 'http:',
npm verb url parsed   slashes: true,
npm verb url parsed   host: 'registry.npmjs.org',
npm verb url parsed   hostname: 'registry.npmjs.org',
npm verb url parsed   pathname: '/socket.io/0.6.16' }
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, Operation not permitted
npm ERR!     at Socket._onConnect (net.js:600:18)
npm ERR!     at IOWatcher.onWritable [as callback] (net.js:186:12)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please use 'sudo' or log in as root to run this command.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     sudo npm "install" "socket.io" "--loglevel" "verbose"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! or set the 'unsafe-perm' config var to true.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm config set unsafe-perm true
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System CYGWIN_NT-5.2-WOW64 1.7.9(0.237/5/3)
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "socket.io" "--loglevel"
"verbose"
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /cygdrive/d/workspace/gits/hummingbird/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Comment: i really hope you don't intend to use node.js on cygwin as a production environment (the part about "windows server 2003 x64" made all alarm bells ring like crazy). node.js on windows is considered unstable and only suited for development. Consider using virtualized servers using VMWare or VirtualBox to run Linux-based systems on your windows servers...

Comment: Oh lord no; just a temp workaround to get something up and running.  Prod will be centos or something but I'm haveing firewall/proxy/don't want to break someone else's dev env and I don't have my own yet issues; womp.. womp..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps your node.js installation was done as root?  Try installing node.js locally under Cygwin, then install npm locally, then install the packages

http://increaseyourgeek.wordpress.com/2010/08/18/install-node-js-without-using-sudo/

Here's the general script I use:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

git clone git://github.com/joyent/node.git /tmp/node
export JOBS=2 # optional, sets number of parallel commands.
mkdir ~/local 
cd /tmp/node
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/node
make
make install
export PATH=$HOME/local/node/bin:$PATH


# install NPM - Node Package Manager
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh

# install necessary node packages
npm install express  (etc..)
```

EDIT:  I did this on npm version 0.3.17..  can't tell you what happens on npm version 1